# PHP - generate multi-dimentional array with all values based on particular key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my array:

```
$arr = array(
  0 => array(
      'title' => 'test1',
      'count' => 4,
      'month' => 'jan-2015'
    ),
  1 => array(
      'title' => 'test2',
      'count' => 10,
      'month' => 'jan-2015'
    ),
  2 => array(
      'title' => 'test3',
      'count' => 14,
      'month' => 'jun-2015'
    ),
  3 => array(
      'title' => 'test4',
      'count' => 45,
      'month' => 'july-2015'
    ),
    4 => array(
      'title' => 'test1',
      'count' => 40,
      'month' => 'jun-2015'
    ),
);
```

I've to convert this array as below:

```
 $arr = array(
  'jan-2015' => array(
      0 => array(
        'title' => 'test1',
        'count' => 4,
      ),
      1 => array(
        'title' => 'test2',
        'count' => 10,
      ),
      2 => array(
        'title' => 'test3',
        'count' => 0,
      ),
      3 => array(
        'title' => 'test4',
        'count' => 0,
      ),
    ),
  'jun-2015' => array(
      0 => array(
        'title' => 'test1',
        'count' => 40,
      ),
      1 => array(
        'title' => 'test2',
        'count' => 0,
      ),
      2 => array(
        'title' => 'test3',
        'count' => 14,
      ),
      3 => array(
        'title' => 'test4',
        'count' => 0,
      ),
   ),
  'july-2015' => array(
      0 => array(
        'title' => 'test1',
        'count' => 0,
      ),
      1 => array(
        'title' => 'test2',
        'count' => 0,
      ),
      2 => array(
        'title' => 'test3',
        'count' => 0,
      ),
      3 => array(
        'title' => 'test4',
        'count' => 45,
     ),
   ),
);
```

That is if there is no title for particular month, then i need to add that title and count will be 0. how to do this?
I've tried this concept:

```
$gen_arr = array_fill_keys(array_column($arr, 'month'), array());
$final_arr = array(); // Array to store the result
foreach ($gen_arr as $gen_key => $gen_value) {
  foreach ($arr as $org_key => $org_value) {
    //temporarily store the original array
    $temp = $org_value;
    if ($gen_key != $temp['month'] && !in_array($temp['title'], $final_arr[$gen_key])) {
      $temp['month'] = $gen_key;
      $temp['count'] = 0;
    }

    $final_arr[$gen_key][] = $temp;
  }
}
return $final_arr;
```

But i can't get what i wanted. Is any other solutions for this?

Comment: You mean you want all 12 months of the year to be the keys of array?

Even the month does not exist in the input array, it should appear in output array like 'feb-2015 => array()' ?

Comment: not like that... Have to add title value only if there is no title in particular 'mon-2016'

Comment: titles are dynamic right?  it could go to test10000..?

Comment: can you give an example of the final array you want generated? I am having a hard time understanding what you are asking

Comment: @Clayton final array is already on the question

Comment: Please, see my code for your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array(
        'title' => 'test1',
        'count' => 4,
        'month' => 'jan-2015'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'title' => 'test2',
        'count' => 10,
        'month' => 'jan-2015'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'title' => 'test3',
        'count' => 14,
        'month' => 'jun-2015'
    ),
    3 => array(
        'title' => 'test4',
        'count' => 45,
        'month' => 'july-2015'
    ),
    4 => array(
        'title' => 'test1',
        'count' => 40,
        'month' => 'jun-2015'
    ),
);

$titles = array_unique( array_column( $arr, 'title' ) );
$months = array_unique( array_column( $arr, 'month' ) );

// Construct an array with the correct structure but with zero counts
$resultingArray = [];
foreach( $months as $month ){
    if( !is_array( $resultingArray[$month] ) ){
        $resultingArray[ $month ] = [];
    }
    foreach( $titles as $title ){
        $resultingArray[ $month ][] = ['title' => $title, 'count' => 0, 'month' => $month ];
    }
}
// And now populate the counts
foreach( $arr as $a ){
    foreach( $resultingArray as $month => &$tempArray ){
        foreach( $tempArray as &$array ){
            if( $a['month'] === $month && $a['title'] === $array['title'] ){
                $array['count'] = $a['count'];
            }
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $resultingArray );
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: @Guru The output is exactly as the one you posted. May be you could explain in more details what exactly you need?

Comment: Great! In that case can you please retract the downvote?

Comment: I need also month in that array

Comment: It have some error. Please look title "test1 test1" for jun-2015. It have count 40. but it code gives 0.

Comment: I literally just copy/pasted the code from my answer and it displays 40 for title `test1` for jun-2015

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see `test1 test1` in the input array

Comment: Is it possible to add all months for current year

Comment: Not that trivial because your names of the months are not consistent, e.g. you have `jun` and `jan` but then you have `july`. If the three letter representation of the month will work for you I can update my answer with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this code for your expectation.

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($arr as $each_arr){
    $month = $each_arr['month'];
    $new_array[$month][] = array(
        'title' => $each_arr['title'],
        'count' => $each_arr['count'],
    );
}

var_dump($new_array);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired array. Please read the requirements carefully!